# AWS login: Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to login to amazon aws with following command on my windows 10 pro in powershell(as admin):

```
Invoke-Expression -Command (aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://**********.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.ama
while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I have tried reconfiguring the aws cli but still same error. I have run an update on the aws cli. It used to work until a few days ago.
The Aws version is:

```
aws-cli/1.11.124 Python/3.6.1 Windows/10 botocore/1.5.87
```

Any good suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset docker to factory defaults helped.

I got the hint from this post:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-login-dial-tcp-lookup-index-docker-io-read-udp-i-o-timeout/14844

Answer (score 1):

Go to Docker settings > network > DNS server:

- Change from automaic to fixed ( default is 8.8.8.8 )